# access $primary in libs from custom theme in apps - Nx

Tags: angular, angular-material, nrwl-nx

I am trying use nrwl/nx and have independent libraries.

In my main apps, i define a diferent theme for apps using material-angular.

Now i would like that lib identify automatic the theme from diferents apps.

For example:

`background: map-get($primary, 50);`

This variable $primary identify automatic the theme from the app that are running.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.